# C# SQL if query returns any rows count

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

What is the simplest and most efficient way to find if a data returns using a query? I'm using `DataTable` like `sqlAdapter.Fill(_table1)` and then doing `_table1.Rows.Count` to see if a datatable has any rows. Is there any classes and functions in C# that just gives me if there are any rows. I don't need the data of the rows. Just the count is what I need. I'm running this query against very large datasets so I don't wanna fill the datatable with all the row info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string myScalarQuery = "select count(*) from TableName";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myScalarQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.Connection.Open();
int count = (int) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
myConnection.Close();
```

Possible optimization of the query per the comments bellow:
Select Top 1 * FROM TableName

Comment: My understanding is that you want a query to determine if a table contains any rows? So why not just run a count query

Comment: Looks good to me (+1). Well, except not being a statically-typed query ;-) *However*, ExecuteScalar has an `object` return type so a Convert.ToInt32 might be in order.

Comment: If you just want to see rows and don't actually need the count maybe SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM  instead of * - to stop processing as soon as it sees a row.

Comment: @user1166147 I agree. I included the count just for the flexibility if the count is needed

Comment: Added your optimization suggestion @user1166147

Comment: Yes, `ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't work on select sql queries. It is always -1.

Comment: calculating Count(*) is more slower than TOP 1 and then check if it returns any records

Comment: @detale yes we added that to the post as an optimization if you don't need the count

Answer (score 8):

The least expensive way is using SqlDataReader's **HasRows** property
**UPDATE**: of course, the most efficient SELECT query will be like "Select Top 1 1 FROM TableName", which doesn't even need to pull any column data.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (rdr.HasRows)
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the SqlCommand look like in this case (for completeness)? Is there as reason to favor this over a COUNT?

Comment: The slowest component will always be the query itself, so the C# part is imo less important.